# RUN in docker without creating a layer

Tags: docker

Is it possible to run a command in the Docker build without creating a new layer.

For example

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
# the following would be like RUN but won't create a layer, it is just used to verify that the build is okay so far.
TEST nginx -t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as far as I know.

Citing from the Dockerfile reference: The `RUN` instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

Multi-stage builds can help to keep the image neat. The idea behind multi-stage builds is to abandon any unnecessary intermediate artifacts.

Docs here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

And an intro to multi-stage builds from the Docker blog: https://blog.docker.com/2017/07/multi-stage-builds/

Comment: can you add a link to "multi-stage builds"?

Comment: Some links added.